# 11.1 GB of "OTHER" out of nowhere?

Tags: iphone, storage

I've had an iPhone 4S for about 1.5 years now. I have never had a problem taking tons of videos and pictures until now. Out of nowhere it says "can not record" because storage is full. I'm like "what, I have only one video".

When I check the usage, I have 11.1 GB of `OTHER`? I have only 1GB of Apps. What do I do to get rid of this? What is it? Calling people at Apple didn't work. I have contacts, notes, texts, apps I don't want to lose.

Answer (score -2):

try deleting all unnecesary items photos videos and also every ios update adds other or ios___ update ___mb

Comment: Photos and videos are not calculated as part of "other". The data used when an iOS update is downloaded is only included in "other" until the update is installed.